# How does a for-loop know when to stop without logical operators?

Tags: javascript, fileapi

I use the following example of how to read multiple files using the file input control and the File API: http://www.htmlgoodies.com/beyond/javascript/read-text-files-using-the-javascript-filereader.html#fbid=ZtHD9f5RFBF .

The question is how does the for loop know when to stop? It seems as if there are no logical conditions that will be tested with each iteration, only the assignment of the file variable. The variable i is incremented but how does it affect the termination of the loop?

I am still new to Javascript.

```
<input type="file" id="fileinput" multiple />
<script type="text/javascript">
  function readMultipleFiles(evt) {
    //Retrieve all the files from the FileList object
    var files = evt.target.files; 

    if (files) {
        for (var i=0, f; f=files[i]; i++) {
              var r = new FileReader();
            r.onload = (function(f) {
                return function(e) {
                    var contents = e.target.result;
                    alert( "Got the file.n" 
                          +"name: " + f.name + "n"
                          +"type: " + f.type + "n"
                          +"size: " + f.size + " bytesn"
                          + "starts with: " + contents.substr(1, contents.indexOf("n"))
                    ); 
                };
            })(f);

            r.readAsText(f);
        }   
    } else {
          alert("Failed to load files"); 
    }
  }

  document.getElementById('fileinput').addEventListener('change', readMultipleFiles, false);
</script>
```

Comment: when `files[i]` will be `undefined/null` then it will stop.

Comment: Mritunjay has already given the answer, but maybe it's good to read more about [`for`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for). For example, you'll find out, that all three parameters are optional.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will stop when `files[i]` will be `undefined/null`.

example

```
var a = [2,3]

for (var i = 0, f; f=a[i]; i++) {
   console.log(f);
};
```

First time a[i] will be 2, it will print 2

Second time a[i] will be 3, it will print 3

Third time a[i] will return `undefined/null`, so expression `f=a[i]` will give result `undefined` and it will stop.